# Karabiner ( KeyRemap4MacBook) Ctrl to Command, preserve Ctrl+Tab and Command+Tab

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

I've been struggling with this for a few hours now. What I want to achieve is I want to map <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> to <kbd>Left Command ⌘</kbd>. However, I want to preserve the functionality of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. So <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Anything</kbd> should be <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Anything</kbd> with the exception of <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
What I could achieve:

- Leave <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> as they are (default)
- Map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> (in this case <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> = <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
- Map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> and map <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (in this case <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is not preserved)

(I might want to add some other exceptions in the future, but seeing the basics surely helps).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since both right and left <kbd>⌘</kbd> are identical in functionality (I hope this is the case in your setup), we first map left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to the right <kbd>⌘</kbd>:

```
<autogen>
  __KeyToKey__
  KeyCode::CONTROL_L,
  KeyCode::COMMAND_R
</autogen>
```

Then map right <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>:

```
<autogen>
  __KeyToKey__
  KeyCode::TAB, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_R,
  KeyCode::TAB, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L
</autogen>
```